# Creating and using a dynamic array

Tags: c++, pointers, syntax, quicksort, dynamic-arrays

I have made a dynamic array before and was able to get it to work in my main.cpp file, but for my class I need to create one in a .h file and implement it in my main and set its capacity through a function then return how many items and the capacity of the array. I was able to set the capacity but I get the errors "

> Error E0109 expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must
>   have (pointer-to-) function type" and "Error E0265 member
>   "QuickSort::capacity [with T=int]"".

This is what the code looks like :

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    VS_MEM_CHECK;

    fstream in(argv[1]);
    fstream out(argv[2]);
    string line;
    QuickSort<int> *toBeSorted;

    while (getline(in, line)) {
        if (line.substr(0, 9) == "QuickSort") {
            out << line << endl;
            line = line.erase(0, 9);
            istringstream iss(line);
            int capacity;
            iss >> capacity;
            toBeSorted->Quicksort(0, capacity);
        }
        else if (line.substr(0, 8) == "Capacity") {
            out << line << endl;
            out << toBeSorted->capacity() << endl;
        }
        else if (line.substr(0, 5) == "Clear") {
            out << line << endl;
            out << toBeSorted->size() << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The functions that are not working:

```
size_t capacity() const {
        return capactiy;
    }

size_t size() const {
        return size;
    }
```

The private variables, constructor/destructor, size() and capacity() functions

```
template<typename T>
class QuickSort : public QSInterface <T>{
private:
    size_t capacity;
    size_t size;
    T* qsArray;
public:
    QuickSort() {
        size = 0;
        capacity = 1;
    }
    Quicksort(size_t s, size_t c) {
        size = s;
        capacity = c;
        qsArray = new T[capacity];
    }
    ~QuickSort() {
        delete[] qsArray;
    }
    size_t size() const {
        return size;
    }
    size_t capacity() const {
        return capactiy;
    }
};
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide the code lines on which the errors occure

Comment: Even after you solve your compilation errors: `QuickSort<int> *toBeSorted;` followed by `toBeSorted->Quicksort(0, capacity);` is undefined behavior, due to the fact that `toBeSorted` doesn't point to `QuickSort<int>` object. What is wrong with `QuickSort<int> toBeSorted;`?

Comment: If this is Visual Studio its best to copy the error message from the Output Tab not the errors list.

Comment: I think you need to edit the question and add a [mcve] I am not convinced that the errors occur in the code that is presented.

Comment: You should check if `argc` is atleast 3 before this: `fstream in(argv[1]);  fstream out(argv[2]);`

Comment: main.cpp(35,21): error C2248: 'QuickSort<int>::capacity': cannot access private member declared in class 'QuickSort<int>'

Comment: main.cpp(39,21): error C2248: 'QuickSort<int>::size': cannot access private member declared in class 'QuickSort<int>'

Comment: Those should both be very obvious. The error message tells you the problem. The message says you declared your capacity() and size() member functions as private members instead of public.

Comment: but if they're part of the same class should it not matter if its public or private? I thought that only mattered with inheritance

Comment: So you don't even have capacity() and size() member functions.

Comment: ***if they're part of the same class should it not matter if its public or private?*** Yes. That is the point of public and private. You can't access size or capacity outside of the class because these are private.

Comment: I do have them as member functions sorry I'm kinda new to the forums I don't know how much I need to put up

Comment: You probably should not name your function the same as your member variable.

Comment: `return capactiy;` is a typo.

Comment: changing the names helped thank you

Comment: You should fix the bug that @AlgirdasPreidžius mentioned.